# Does $x^{n/n} = |x|$?

Tags: exponentiation

Just a couple of small technical point here.  If x and n are real numbers, do we have to write $x ^ {n/n} = |x|$?  Or can we just reduce it to $x^{n/n} = x$?

One reason I ask is because then we would arrive at $x = x^1 = x ^{n/n} = |x|$.  Does this mean, then, that $x$ is not equal to $x^{n/n}$?  Or that $x ^ 1$ is not equal to  $x^{n/n}$?

Similarly, if I write $(\sqrt x)^2 = x^{2/2} = \sqrt{x^2}$, am I correct?  Or does the order matter here?

Comment: $x^{n/n}$ = $x$ since $n/n = 1$.  I think you might find $(x^n)^{1/n}$ is a more interesting expression...

Comment: $\sqrt{(x)}^2 = |x|$, not $x$

Answer (score 7):

You are incorrect.

Once you are dealing with non-integer exponents, you either only define $x^y$ for $x$ positive, or you no longer have the property that $(x^y)^z = x^{yz}$ in general.

The expression $x^y$ gets complicated when $y$ is rational, it gets stranger when $y$ is irrational, and it gets insane when $y$ is a complex number.  :)

Finally, the expression $x^{n/n}= x^1$ for any $x$, since $n/n=1$, so we have the order of operations - $n/n$ isn't some representation that is "like" $1$, it is $1$.

If you define $x^1=|x|$, you are losing a lot of rich mathematics. :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing $x^{n/n}$ with $(x^n)^{1/n}$. These are not quite equivalent (nor are any of them equivalent to $(x^{1/n})^n$. As others have pointed out, $x^{n/n}=x^1=x$.

More interestingly, consider $(x^n)^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{x^n}$. Note that if $x\in \Bbb R$ and $n$ is a positive integer, then:

> $$ \sqrt[n]{x^n}=\begin{cases}
> x & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
> |x| & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
> \end{cases}$$

Comment: but $ x^{\frac{3}{3}}=x=x^{\frac{2*3}{2*3}}=\left | x \right |$ !!

Comment: Again, you have to be careful with parentheses.  Ordinarily $x^{\frac{a}{b}}$ would be interpreted as $x^{(a/b)}$, i.e. first you take $a/b$, then $x$ to that power.  So if $a = b$ (and, of course, $b \ne 0$), $a/b = 1$ and $x^{\frac{a}{b}} = x$.  In particular, $x^{\frac{2 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 3}} = x$, not $|x|$.   $(x^{2 \cdot 3})^{1/(2\cdot 3)}$ would be $|x|$, but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

if we interpret $x^{n/n}$ as $(x^{n})^{1/n}$ or $(x^{1/n})^{n}$, they are different:

The first one contains a multivalued function
$$
f(z) = z^{1/q}
$$
so that $(x^{n})^{1/n} = \{xe^{2\pi i/n}, i = 0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$

The second one can be simplified to just a single value $x$, since suppose $x = re^{i\theta}$, then
$$
x^{1/n} = \{r e^{(2\pi i + \theta)/n}, i = 0,1,\ldots,n-1\}
$$
Then the mapping $z \mapsto z^n$ merges then together to a single $x$ again.